# cordova build error Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED on linux:arm64

Tags: java, linux, cordova, gradle, android-sdk-tools

I made a cordova project on kali linux (running on vm using termux in android: arm64). when i run `cordova run browser` it's run successfull. but when i run `cordova build android` it is failed with these errors

```
$ cordova build android
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/Android-Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: /usr/Android-Sdk
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 2 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-linux Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-linux Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-linux Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-linux Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-linux Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-linux Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-linux Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-linux Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 8s
28 actionable tasks: 18 executed, 10 up-to-date
Command failed with exit code 1: /root/hello/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /root/hello/platforms/android/build.gradle
$
```

whats gone wrong with this;
gradle is showing "gradle daemon 1 incomptible" this problem with device architecture?

cordova requierments output here:-

```
$ cordova requirements                                     
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-29,android-28
Gradle: installed /usr/gradle/bin/gradle
$
```

and gradle -version output are-

```
$ gradle -version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.7.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-11-16 17:09:24 UTC
Revision:     2972ff02f3210d2ceed2f1ea880f026acfbab5c0

Kotlin:       1.3.72
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.8 compiled on May 10 2020
JVM:          1.8.0_271 (Oracle Corporation 25.271-b09)
OS:           Linux 3.18.120-perf-gd85b39b aarch64
$
```

Comment: Is your antivirus blocking the aapt2 executable? You can find "aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-linux/aapt2" in your gradle cache and try executing it from the command line to see if it's the executable itself that is having issues

Answer (score 0):

The aapt2 binary is only compatibale for amd64 but not for arm64/aarch64.
You can look for the aapt2 binary in `~/.gradle/caches` and try replace it with this version: https://github.com/JonForShort/android-tools/tree/master/build/android-11.0.0_r33/aapt2/arm64-v8a/bin

That might work.
Here is a blogpost explaining how to do it:
https://linuxtut.com/en/ec63aa8bff5103982156/

Answer (score -1):

OK, I am no expert at this, but I have encountered a similar problem and I fixed it by running
`cordova run build` 
with my internet connectivity switched on. I think you need an internet connection to build cordova apps.

Comment: Isn't it that the syntax of that command is ```cordova run [platform]```, of which ```build``` is not a platform?